# How to define Related Product for Knowledge article in Dynamics crm?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016, knowledge-management

I have a Knowledge article and also i set a Product in Related Products of this article.
problem is that when i open my product , My "Knowledge base Search"'s grid is empty , and i can't find any article in it ..

Comment: How is this related to programming? https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: dynamics crm is a Development Framework, i develop some solutions for this system. codes developed in .net MVC

Comment: Your problem seems like matter of standard system tools or customization done by clicking. I don't see any coding involved in your problem.